# Reading an XML file while it is being written to

Tags: c#, .net, xml, read-write, file-access

I have a long-running REST API method which compiles an XML file. The user makes a request to initiate this compilation, the basic file is created, and the user is then given a unique ID with which to query for progress.

When called, the progress-reading method opens the file with read-only access, instantiates an `XDocument` object and counts the number of elements therein.

The code which **populates** the XML file is accessed with

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fs);

    foreach (...)
    {
        // add the element to xmlDoc

        xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
    }
}
```

And the code which **reads** the file in order to count the number of elements

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fs);

    // count elements
}
```

However, in the **populating** method an exception is thrown on `xmlDoc.Save(filePath);`

> The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.

As I understood it, opening the FileStream with `FileShare.Read` allows another process to open the file with read-only access (and I believe this is happening) and likewise using `FileShare.ReadWrite` in the reading/counting method would permit the populating process to open the file with write-access.

Why doesn't the above code allow both processes to do what I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
xmlDoc.Save(filePath)
```

you pass filename, so `XmlDocument` does not use your `fs` stream you opened for writing. Instead it opens yet another stream internally, which of course fails because you already have one stream opened for writing.

Instead, seek to the beginning of the stream and then call

```
xmlDoc.Save(fs);
```

You may also set stream length to zero before saving (to truncate old contents), though not completely sure irs necessary.

Comment: Could you explain the reasons behind the suggestion that "You may also set stream length to zero before saving (to truncate old contents)"? Wouldn't setting the stream _length_ to 0 before saving remove the stream's contents? Or perhaps you meant to write that I should set the length to the current position?

Comment: You first open a stream with existing contents and read that contents into XDocument (XDocument.Load). Suppose file was 1000 bytes. Before saving, stream has length 1000 and position 1000. You seek to position 0 and save. Now suppose new document has length 900. IF XDocument.Save does not set stream length itself to 900, you may end up having 900 bytes of new document + 100 bytes of previous document, for a total of 1000, and that is not what you want. Since I'm not sure how XDocument.Save works internally, I suggested to truncate stream before saving, to be sure.

Comment: OK, 2 points to make:(1) The contents being written to the file will only grow; when opened, the FileStream will never be shorter than it has been. (2) While implementing this I'm getting the exception "An attempt was made to move the position before the beginning of the stream". This happens at seemingly random times - sometimes during the first query-read, other times much later.

Comment: 1. If you sequentially add elements to the file, you don't need to use XDocument, because saving it will overwrite whole file, not add something to the end. Well you _can_ use XDocument, it will just be not very efficient. Instead you can use some streaming xml api (XmlWriter and so on). 2. On which line exactly it throws such exception and in which method (read or write)?

Comment: Exception is thrown on `using (var fs = new FileStream...` - during the read-only operation.

Comment: Well to be honest, the whole approach is flawed and is subject to many problems. First, you can always read in the middle of the write, when there is no well-formed document at all (imagine populating process writes "<elemen" and you try to read that. Instead, just store the progress in memory (as a number) and when user queries for progress - read from memory. If you cannot use memory, nor database for that, at least create separate file (your_document.xml.progress) and store the number there, saving from time to time.

Comment: Thanks @Evk - I think what I'll do is save progress to a separate XML file - a simple count - and put a lock on this file while it's being written to. You've been very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. Be careful when reading that count file - it still might throw that "process cannot access file..." error in very rare cases when write happens at the same time. So you have to do that in a loop with multiple tries.